# Enum and inclusion in models.rb not fetching the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

Hello I'm new to rails

I am trying to create an e-commerce website using rails. Refering the Agile Web development book.
**This is the order.rb**

```
  validates :name, :address, :email, presence: true
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  validates :pay_type, inclusion: pay_types.keys
  enum pay_type: {
    'Debit card' => 0,
    'Credit card' => 1,
    'Net Banking' => 2
  }
```

**I m getting error like this**

```
undefined local variable or method `pay_types' for #<Class:0x00007f22401067b0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined the enum after you've used it. Instead, define it before.

```
  enum pay_type: {
    'Debit card' => 0,
    'Credit card' => 1,
    'Net Banking' => 2
  }

  validates :pay_type, inclusion: pay_types.keys
```

The validation is unnecessary. Trying to use a value which is not in the enum will result in an ArgumentError. You may wish to validate its presence if it is required.

```
validates :pay_type, presence: true
```